# how can i show retrieved data from database in not a present view controller but another one in ios with using swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, exception

i'm making database in main view controller and now i want to retrieve its stored data in to next view controller but i don't know, can any one give me answer of it.

a code block:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths =
        NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
                                            .UserDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
    let path = (docsDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("contacts.db")


    databasePath = path

    if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {

        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if contactDB == nil {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        if contactDB.open() {
            let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT)"
            if !contactDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt) {
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
            contactDB.close()
        } else {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }
    }

}
```

using this code i made database 
but how can i retrieve its data in next view controller again i'm repeating not on a same page another page i want to display this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not implement your database in a view controller but in your app delegate.

Example:

```
// declare global database
var myGlobalDB:FMDatabase?

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // do your database init stuff here
    ...
    myGlobalDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    ...
}
```

Your myGlobalDB will be available from anywhere.

Comment: is it required that my table must be in app delegate then can i get its data in any other view controller ???

Comment: What he means is that you separate the model (data) from the view and the controller. You data and datacontroller are in separate files than you tableView and your tableView requests the data from the controller to present in it's own view.

Answer (score 0):

While what Michael said is correct if you want to push data to the next ViewController use a segue.

If you create a variable to hold the data in the SecondViewController:

```
var database : FMDatabase?
```

and in your `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifier" {
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            vc.database = self.contactDB
        }
    }
}
```

Change `as? SecondViewController` to the classname of your Second View Controller and change `"your identifier"` to the segue identifier you use to switch to the Second View Controller. If only 1 segue is used than it isn't required but it is good practice to use.

Comment: u don't understand my question

Comment: actually i'm aking that i have one database in my app delegate as said Michael, now i want to retrieve its data on the other view controller's label or textfields then how can i ???

Comment: You were asking specifically to view the data you fetched in the earlier view controller. This is how you pass data along.

Comment: Michael i had changed but now i can't add data to my database's table:( that's why can't retrieve also...

Comment: as per segue how can i retrieve data from database can u please tell me....@Emptyless

Comment: If you retrieved the data in your FirstViewController just reference the variable you stored it in and pass it to vc.database as per code sample

Comment: i don't want it because in further my project i have to face this problem again.

Comment: is it possible then i can use this segue in different viewcontrollers ???